# Extracting information from XML-Files by URL-Source takes a lot of time

Tags: xpath, sax, jdom-2

I would like to extract specific information from 108 Xml files. The general source is also a XML-File with further URLs as resources. 
[XML-Source](http://www.steinheim-institut.de/cgi-bin/epidat?info=resources-mz1)
The static method getURL() extracts the URLs in order to set them as URL-paths within a for loop in the main method. The programm works, but it takes approx. 5 minutes to get the data from all files. Any ideas how to increase the performance?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.Namespace;
import org.jdom2.filter.Filters;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathExpression;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathFactory;

public class XmlReader2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        for (int i = 0; i < getURL().size(); i++) {
            URL url = new URL(getURL().get(i));



            try {
                Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(url);


                final String getDeath = String
                        .format("//ns:teiHeader/ns:profileDesc/ns:particDesc/ns:listPerson/ns:person/ns:death");

                XPathExpression<Element> xpath = XPathFactory.instance().compile(getDeath, Filters.element(), null,
                        Namespace.getNamespace("ns", "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"));

                String test;
                for (Element elem : xpath.evaluate(doc)) {
                    test = elem.getValue();
                    if (elem.getAttributes().size() != 0) {
                        test = elem.getAttributes().get(0).getValue();
                    }
                    System.out.println(elem.getName() + ": " + test); 
                }

            } catch (org.jdom2.JDOMException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getURL() throws IOException {

        List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        URL urlSource = new URL("http://www.steinheim-institut.de:80/cgi-bin/epidat?info=resources-mz1");
        try {
            Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(urlSource);

            final String getURL = String.format("/collection");
            XPathExpression<Element> xpath = XPathFactory.instance().compile(getURL, Filters.element());

            int i = 0;
            for (Element elem : xpath.evaluate(doc)) {
                while (i != elem.getChildren().size()) {
                    String url = elem.getChildren().get(i).getAttributes().get(1).getValue();
                    // System.out.println(url);
                    urlList.add(url);
                    i++;
                }
            }


        } catch (org.jdom2.JDOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A delay of this order may be caused by fetching files from the web. Find a tool for monitoring HTTP requests issued from your machine to see what is going on. Look in particular for requests for common W3C files such as the XHTML DTD: because these files are requested so often, W3C deliberately injects a delay into the process to encourage people to use local copies of the files. If it turns out that this is the problem, there are various techniques you can use to access cached local copies.

Having said that, I'm puzzled by the logic of your code. The method `getURL()` appears to fetch and parse the document at `http://www.steinheim-institut.de:80/cgi-bin/epidat?info=resources-mz1` every time it is called, and yet you are calling it within a loop, even using `getURL().size()` as your terminating condition.